# Migration executes from drush but not from UI

Tags: drush, migrations

I have a list of migrations (custom ones but following the guidelines).
The migrations have no problems being executed from console with drush mim but if I try to execute them from the migrations UI I get a very long error

```
Error: Class 'Drush\Commands\DrushCommands' not found in include() (line 23 of /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php)
#0 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#1 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/cashbac6/...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Drupal\\migrate_...')
#3 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/MigrateTools.php(24): spl_autoload_call('Drupal\\migrate_...')
#4 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/MigrateExecutable.php(107): Drupal\migrate_tools\MigrateTools::buildIdList(Array)
#5 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/MigrateBatchExecutable.php(60): Drupal\migrate_tools\MigrateExecutable->__construct(Object(Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration), Object(Drupal\migrate\MigrateMessage), Array)
#6 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Form/MigrationExecuteForm.php(216): Drupal\migrate_tools\MigrateBatchExecutable->__construct(Object(Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration), Object(Drupal\migrate\MigrateMessage), Array)
#7 [internal function]: Drupal\migrate_tools\Form\MigrationExecuteForm->submitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#8 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormSubmitter.php(112): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormSubmitter.php(52): Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#10 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(591): Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#11 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(320): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('migration_execu...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#12 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/FormController.php(91): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object(Drupal\migrate_tools\Form\MigrationExecuteForm), Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#13 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch))
#14 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(573): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#16 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#17 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
#18 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#19 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#20 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#21 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#22 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#23 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#24 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#25 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#26 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#27 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(694): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#28 /home/cashbac6/public_html/dev/stage_angel/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#29 {main}
```

Any idea where to look for issues?

Comment: Were you able to find solution for your issue?